# missing reference in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, arcgis-server

i am using visual studio  2010 and arcgis server 10 to develop Server Object Extension and while developing the manager property page esri.arcgis.servermanager is missing how to include this assembly reference in my project.
i am using this link for help http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_develop_a_property_page_for_the_REST_SOE/000100000nwm000000/
plz help me asap.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.  Or try gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of: I am not familiar with ArcGIS Server, but I might be able to help you with some general remarks.

Check that the assemblies listed under step 6 of the link you posted are visible under *References* (when you expand it) in the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio. If not, you'll need to add them.

To add a reference to a assemblies, right-click the *References* item in your Solution Explorer and click *Add Reference...*. Find the assemblies that you have to include (e.g. `ESRI.ArcGIS.ServerManager`). This is essentially steps 5 and 6 of the link you posted. If you've done this correctly, they should appear under *References* in your Solution Explorer.

Note that the documentation states that the `ServerManager` requires the Web Applications component of ArcGIS Server. Ensure that you have this, or it might not work.